# Two playing cards packages show vastly different performance

Tags: compiling, pstricks, warnings, performance, cards

I am experimenting typesetting poker hands with two packages. I unexpectedly spotted a huge performance difference between the two.

```
$ cat pst-poker.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\begin{document}
\crdtwos\crdsevd\crdtens\crdAh\crdfours: High Card\\
\crdfivec\crdfiveh\crdeigd\crdsixh\crdtwoh: One Pair\\
\crdfourd\crdsixc\crdKh\crdeigc\crdtres: High Card\\
\crdeigc\crdeigs\crdsixc\crdJs\crdQc: One Pair\\
\crdsevd\crdfourh\crdnined\crdAc\crdJc: High Card\\
\end{document}
```

```
$ time xelatex pst-poker.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pst-poker.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-03>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-poker/pst-poker.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfil
tered.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
`PSTricks' v3.19  <2023/04/30> (tvz,hv)
--- We are running latex or xelatex ---
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-color.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-arrows.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-dots.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for LaTeX+dvipdfmx
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-blur/pst-blur.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-blur/pst-blur.tex
 v2.0, 2005/09/08))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multido/multido.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/multido/multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-fill/pst-fill.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-fill/pst-fill.tex
`PST-Fill' v1.02, 2021/10/01 (tvz,dg,hv))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)
No file pst-poker.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/utxsyc.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--9

[1] (./pst-poker.aux) )


%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY



%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY

(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on pst-poker.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on pst-poker.log.

real    0m17.509s
user    0m13.707s
sys     0m3.596s
```

```
$ time xelatex-unsafe ./pst-poker.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode
(./pst-poker.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-03>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-poker/pst-poker.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfil
tered.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
`PSTricks' v3.19  <2023/04/30> (tvz,hv)
--- We are running latex or xelatex ---
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-color.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-arrows.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-dots.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for LaTeX+dvipdfmx
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-blur/pst-blur.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-blur/pst-blur.tex
 v2.0, 2005/09/08))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multido/multido.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/multido/multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-fill/pst-fill.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-fill/pst-fill.tex
`PST-Fill' v1.02, 2021/10/01 (tvz,dg,hv))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)
(./pst-poker.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/utxsyc.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--9

[1] (./pst-poker.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on pst-poker.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on pst-poker.log.

real    0m16.928s
user    0m13.405s
sys     0m3.327s
```

```
$ cat JeuxCartes.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{JeuxCartes}
\begin{document}
\AffCartesJeu{2P § 7K § 10P § AC § 4P}: High Card\\
\AffCartesJeu{5T § 5C § 8K § 6C § 2C}: One Pair\\
\AffCartesJeu{4K § 6T § RC § 8T § 3P}: High Card\\
\AffCartesJeu{8T § 8P § 6T § VP § DT}: One Pair\\
\AffCartesJeu{7K § 4C § 9K § AT § VT}: High Card\\
\end{document}
```

```
$ time pdflatex ./JeuxCartes.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./JeuxCartes.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-03>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/JeuxCartes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfil
tered.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/listofitems/listofitems.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/listofitems/listofitems.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/simplekv/simplekv.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/simplekv/simplekv.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xinttools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintkernel.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/randomlist/randomlist.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/randomlist/randomlist.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryscopes.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file JeuxCartes.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Overfull \hbox (90.6531pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--9
[][][][][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 :

Overfull \hbox (75.65309pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--9
[][][][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 :

Overfull \hbox (75.65312pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--9
[][][][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 :

Overfull \hbox (75.65314pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--9
[][][][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 :

Overfull \hbox (75.65309pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--9
[][][][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 :

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--9

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} </usr/
local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-2P.pdf> </usr/lo
cal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-7K.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-7K.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-10P.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-10P.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group incl
uded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-AC.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-AC.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-4P.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-4P.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-5T.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-5T.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-5C.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-5C.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-8K.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-8K.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-6C.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-6C.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-2C.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-2C.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-4K.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-4K.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-6T.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-6T.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-RC.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-RC.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-8T.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-8T.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-3P.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-3P.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-8P.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-8P.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-VP.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-VP.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-DT.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-DT.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
>] [2 </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-4C.p
df> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-9K.pdf


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-9K.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-AT.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-AT.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
> </usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeuxcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-VT.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jeu
xcartes/CaJ-PokeRv1-VT.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group inclu
ded in a single page
>] (./JeuxCartes.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2023/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on JeuxCartes.pdf (2 pages, 462082 bytes).
Transcript written on JeuxCartes.log.

real    0m0.349s
user    0m0.308s
sys     0m0.040s
```

As you can see, a MWE using `JeuxCartes` took less than half a second, while that using `pst-poker` takes more than 16 seconds. Is it the invocation of `pstricks` and other related utilities that drag the process? I've never seen a few lines of TeX code take more than 2 secodns to compile before.

Comment: Welcome to teX.SE!

Comment: pstricks in xelatex is slow. Every use triggers an external ghostscript call. (You could use lualatex instead (that needs `\DocumentMetadata{}` before the class), that is much faster with pstricks.